# Store in environment variable

Tags: programming, environment-variables, grep, cut-command

I tried storing the contents of a file in an environment variable using one of those commands.

```
a= cut -f 1 abc.txt

cut -f 1 abc.txt >a
```

neither works .

So , can anybody help me out?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
a= cut -f 1 abc.txt
```

This doesn't work, this will assign the word 'command' cut to the variable a. The correct syntax is

```
a=`cut -f 1 abc.txt`
```

Now you can run the command

```
echo $a
```

and check the result. Works

---

The second command

```
cut -f 1 abc.txt >a
```

This will redirect the output of the command `cut -f 1 abc.txt` into a newly created file named a and not a variable a.